# execute php command using C# windows service not working

Tags: c#, php, pdf, windows-services, command-prompt

I'm writing a program which creates a PDF at various intervals of time. I'm trying to run a PHP command to generate the PDF using a windows service (C#).

My code works just fine from within a C# windows desktop app, but when I try to use it in a windows service, nothing happens and the **exit** line appears in output without generating a PDF file.

Here is my code:

```
     ProcessStartInfo cmdStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            cmdStartInfo.FileName = @"cmd.exe";
            cmdStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            cmdStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            cmdStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            cmdStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            cmdStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            cmdStartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
            cmdStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            cmdStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = WorkingDirectory; //refers to directory where php file exist.

            Process cmdProcess = new Process();
            cmdProcess.StartInfo = cmdStartInfo;
            cmdProcess.ErrorDataReceived += cmdProcess_ErrorDataReceived;
            cmdProcess.OutputDataReceived += cmdProcess_OutputDataReceived;
            cmdProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            cmdProcess.Start();
            cmdProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
            cmdProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();
            cmdProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"php.exe -c  GeneratePDF.php ");
            cmdProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine("Exit");
```

Comment: Does anything show up in `cmdProcess_ErrorDataReceived` or `cmdProcess_OutputDataReceived`? Chances are it's a permissions issue.

Comment: In error data received nothing, but in output data received it shows command line i am trying to run then line of exit . Forget to mention that account type is local system which i think has high permission. Also i tried to play in service properties to make it allow interact with desktop while my cmd is non-window .